# SQLite Store strings that start with zero e.g. "001"

Tags: sqlite, types

Which data type do I choose in SQLite to store a string such as "001" in the database.

I've tried using *Text* but when I go to type in the string 001, it drops the 00 and only puts a 1.

I've even tried using "blob" data type but still no luck. They all drop the zeros before the digit.

Comment: What makes you think the zeros are being dropped? I assume the DB is actually storing the correct data but whatever GUI client you are using to look at the data is formatting it as a number. What happenes if you write code to pull the string back out of the DB? Does it still have the zeros then?

Comment: Can you share the code that is displaying the data?  It may be interpreting the results as a number and removing the zeros (not sqllite)

Comment: @JesseWebb thanks for the hint. I am using Navicat for SQLite and just like am used to testing Mysql, I inserted the data directly. Navicat in its own wisdom was dropping the zeros. When I use an insert statement while quoting the zeros, it works.

Comment: Answer here is do not use a GUI tool to insert data into SQLite. It won't work as expected especially in the case described above. Other databases maybe but not SQLite..

Comment: @lukik - IMO, the best SQLite GUI tool currently available is [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), the Firefox plugin. I would suggest trying it out if you are unhappy with how Navicat behaves.

Answer (score 6):

Works ok for me:

```
sqlite> create table sotest
   ...> (
   ...> col1 varchar(20)
   ...> );
sqlite>
sqlite> select * from sotest;
sqlite>
sqlite> insert into sotest values ('001');
sqlite> select * from sotest;
001
sqlite>
```

Maybe you weren't quoting your strings? For example:

```
sqlite> insert into sotest values ('001');
sqlite> select * from sotest;
001
sqlite> insert into sotest values (001);
sqlite> select * from sotest;
001
1
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 2):

Column type should set to varchar, not string, if type is string zero will be dropped automatically.